# Android: SharedPreferences sometimes causes NullPointException error

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I published my app and I found out SharedPreferences sometimes causes NullPointException a few times. Mostly it works well. I still don't figure out the reason and when the error causes.

My code and log is like this.

`Activity`

```
protected void onCreate(...) {
    super.onCreare(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);

  　// NullPointException here
    ASharedPreferences.saveCurrentNumber();
    ASharedPreferences.getCurrentNumber();
}
```

`ASharedPreferences.java`

```
public class ASharedPreferences {

    private static final String PREF_NAME = 'Number';
    private static ASharedPreferences sInstance;
    private static SharedPreferences sSharedPref;
    private static SharedPreferences.Editor sEditor;

    private ASharedPreferences(Context context) {
        sSharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        sEditor = sSharedPref.edit();
    }


    public static void init(Context context) {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = new ASharedPreferences(context);
        }
    }

    public static void saveCurrentNumber() {
        sEditor.putInt("current_number", getCurrentNumber() + 1);
        sEditor.apply();
    }

    public static int getCurrentNumber() {
        return sSharedPref.getInt("current_number", 0);
    }

}
```

Log is here. But it seems useless.

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException:
>
> at com...ASharedPreferences.getCurrentNumber (ASharedPreferences.java:30)
>
> at com.ASharedPreferences.saveCurrentNumber (ASharedPreferences.java:25)
>
> at com...Activity.onCreate (Activity.java:63)

Why does it cause NullPointException even though it is set default value?

What is the cause possibly?

## Update

`MainActivity.java`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ASharedPreferences.init(this);
}
```

Comment: Did you initialise the `ASharedPreferences` class with the `init` method?

Comment: @Edric Yes of course. In the first activity, it it is initialized. As I mentioned above, mostly it works well. This error sometimes happens.

Comment: Can you share the initialization code?

Comment: @Zachary I put the part. Please take a look.

Comment: Checking it now

Comment: Try Gowtham's solution. It should work.

Comment: @Zachary I know it works as well. But is it more safe than my approach?

Comment: Since you are using MODE_PRIVATE,  it is fine

Comment: @Zachary ah sorry I mean is this approach less likely to cause error?

Comment: yes. give it a try. It should work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach instead of creating instance of the class.

```
protected void onCreate(...) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);

  　// NullPointException here
    ASharedPreferences.saveCurrentNumber(MyActivity.this);
    int n=ASharedPreferences.getCurrentNumber(MyActivity.this);
}
```

```
public class ASharedPreferences {

    private static final String PREF_NAME = 'Number';

    public static void saveCurrentNumber(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences sSharedPref=context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
       SharedPreferences.Editor sEditor=sSharedPref.edit();
        sEditor.putInt("current_number", getCurrentNumber(context) + 1);
        sEditor.apply();
    }

    public static int getCurrentNumber(Context context) {
       SharedPreferences sSharedPref=context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
       SharedPreferences.Editor sEditor=sSharedPref.edit();
        return sSharedPref.getInt("current_number", 0);
    }

}
```

Comment: I will try to do this way. Could you explain the reason this approach is less likely to cause the error?

Comment: Static keyword in Java is meant for variable , method and inner classes to share the resources with multiple objects.Not for object itself.And then there is no need to create an instance here.And Singleton approach without synchronizing may lead to creating multiple instance in multi threading application. Try my answer and post an update in comments.

Comment: Okay thanks I will see if it works well. It will take time.